# init an array in initWithNibName

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I am trying to set up an array in my UIViewController. The nib gets loaded into my app, sometimes repeatedly. I am adding this to my initWithNibName to init the array

```
NSMutableArray *temp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"one",@"two",@"three",@"four",@"five",nil];
    [self setScoreArray:temp];
    [temp release];
```

scoreArray is a MutableArray with synthesized properties. When I go to access the array in viewDidLoad I get [[self scoreArray] count] as 0. Also, when I load the nib repeatedly I get a bad access error. Any suggestions? Am I missing a step. Thanks. I am synthesizing the property for the array, in my class declaration:

```
    NSMutableArray *_scoreArray;
```

then

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *scoreArray;
```

then in my implementation

```
@synthesize scoreArray =_scoreArray;
```

and in my dealloc

```
    [_scoreArray release], _scoreArray = nil;
```

I'm editing this post to show how I'm loading the nibs with my RootViewController

```
- (void) createNewSlide:(NSInteger)slideIndex {

NSDictionary *slideObj = (NSDictionary *)[[self slidesDataSource] objectAtIndex:slideIndex - 1];
NSString *currentTitle = [slideObj objectForKey:@"title"];
[[self slideTitle] setText:currentTitle];
NSString *currentContent = [slideObj objectForKey:@"contentString"];
NSString *currentContentType = [slideObj objectForKey:@"contentType"];

if ([self currentVC] != nil) {
        [[self currentVC] reset];
        [self setCurrentVC:nil];
}

if ([currentContentType isEqualToString:@"slide"]) 
{

    [[self containerViewController] loadImage:currentContent];

}
else if ([currentContentType isEqualToString:@"quiz"])
{
    NSInteger quizNum = [[slideObj objectForKey:@"quizNum"] integerValue];
    NSLog(@"%s%@%d",__FUNCTION__,@"quizNum ",quizNum);
    QuizViewController *quizView = [[QuizViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"QuizViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self setCurrentVC:quizView];
     [quizView release];
    [[self containerViewController] replaceSlideWithViewController:[self currentVC]];
}
else if ([currentContentType isEqualToString:@"PIDView"])
{
    PIDViewController *PIDView = [[PIDViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PIDView" bundle:nil];
    [self setCurrentVC:PIDView];
    [PIDView release];
    [[self containerViewController] replaceSlideWithViewController:[self currentVC]];

}
else if ([currentContentType isEqualToString:@"LoginView"])
{
    LoginViewController *login = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginView" bundle:nil];
    [self setCurrentVC:login];
    [login release];
    [[self containerViewController] replaceSlideWithViewController:[self currentVC]];
}

else if ([currentContentType isEqualToString:@"VakView"])
{
    VakViewController *vakView = [[VakViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"VakView" bundle:nil];
    [self setCurrentVC:vakView];
    [vakView release];
    [[self containerViewController] replaceSlideWithViewController:[self currentVC]];
}

else if ([currentContentType isEqualToString:@"PlanView"])
{
    PlanViewController *planView = [[PlanViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PlanView" bundle:nil];
    [self setCurrentVC:planView];
    [planView release];
    [[self containerViewController] replaceSlideWithViewController:[self currentVC]];
```

}

Thanks for your insights.
PlanView is the one that causes the problem. But it is not when it loads, it's when something else loads after it. I have run the analyzer and it reports no memory leaks.
BTW, currentVC is a synthesized property.

Comment: How are you declaring the `scoreArray` property? Are you including the `retain` directive? Otherwise I believe the default is `assign`.

Comment: First off, I would clean up the code by using the dot syntax and an autoreleased factory method of NSMutableArray: `self.scoreArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"one",@"two",@"three",@"four",@"five",nil];` As to the actual problem, I'm not quite sure. Can you post the backtrace of the EXC_BAD_ACCESS error?

Comment: EXC_BAD_ACCESS is almost always indicative of a memory management error. Try running the static analyzer on your project - it excels at finding such bugs.

Comment: Yes, I'm using retain on the synthesized property.

Answer (score 3):

How is your UIViewController being created? If it is being created via another nib, then `-initWithNibName:bundle:` doesn't get called. Instead, `-initWithCoder:` and `-awakeFromNib` are called.